# Has Bang ever used the abandonment in the anime?

Tags: one-punch-man

According to the One Punch Man Encyclopedia, Bang has a technique called "The abandonment" which allows him to increase his powers. Has he ever used this technique in the anime series or ovas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Wikia](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Bang) states:

[image]

And it's written *clearly* that:

> Bang is seen utilizing this to prepare for his fight with Elder Centipede, so Bomb and Genos could escape with the unconscious heroes.

Which is right when King interferes the fight. He doesnt state the technique's name. But he powers up:

[image]

Comment: I like that emphasis on 'clearly', seeing as knowing about the technique would have required you to visit the wikia, it would be impossible to miss out this much information..